# Rails redirects to the wrong address

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I create URL for sign out from system:

```
<li><%= link_to("Выйти", "http://bookworm.az:3000/logout") %></li>
```

Sessions Controllers Destroy action:

```
def destroy
    session[:username] = nil
    redirect_to "http://bookworm.az:3000/login"
end
```

And my routes are:

```
get '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
```

But when I click on link it redirects me to the

```
http://bookworm.az:3000/logout
```

Not to

```
http://bookworm.az:3000/login
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is breaking Rails conventions. You should use this one instead:

**view.rb**

```
link_to "Delete", session_path(current_session), method: :delete
```

You should not change **routes.rb** resources. Keep it simple:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :sessions
```

Also, you should use URL helper that Rails generates from your **routes.rb** file, instead of using an absolute path (unless there is no other way).